# Access minkube cluster from outside the host machine

Tags: networking, kubernetes, minikube

I have a cloud instance up & running, I installed `minikube` on it and created a cluster, single `Pod` with `NodePort` service.

I know that this is not the best practice while setup `kubernetes` cluster

**The issue is** :
Everything works fine if tested from inside the host machine (the cloud instance) but I am trying to reach the cluster from outside the machine using it's `external-ip` address, how to do that?

Deployment: the image is public if you want to test

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: python-app-deployment
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        tag: pythonapp
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: pythonapp
          image: atefhares/mypythonapp:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8000
          env:
            - name: ENVIRONMENT
              value: DEV
            - name: HOST
              value: "localhost"
            - name: PORT
              value: "8000"
            - name: REDIS_HOST
              value: "redis-service"
            - name: REDIS_PORT
              value: "6379"
            - name: REDIS_DB
              value: "0"
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      tag: pythonapp
```

Service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: python-app-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - nodePort: 30001
      port: 8000
  selector:
    tag: pythonapp
```

Database deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: redis
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: redis
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: redis
          image: redis:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 6379
  selector:
      matchLabels:
        name: redis
```

Database service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis-service
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 6379
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    name: redis
```

Comment: Did you create the firewall rule to access the nodport externally? Please post your service spec.

Comment: @KoopaKiller Yes I added the rule I am sure it's not the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because `minkube` creates a `VM` or a `docker container` to be used as worker/node. that's why the cluster is not by default accessible from outside the machine.

To fix this issue use `minikube` without `drivers` as follows:

```
sudo minikube start --driver=none
```

This will enforce `minikube` to not create any `VMs` or `Containers` and will directly use resources from the host.

Also, make sure everything works fine in your `deployment` and you will be able to access the cluster using the machine's `external-ip` address and `service` port.

Know more [here](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/none/)

---

**PS**: This is not a setup for production environments!

Answer (score 0):

With minikube, you have to expose the service also with minikube.

Example:
`minikube service yourservicename` [1]

You can list all your minikube services with `minikube service list`

[1]https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/hello-minikube/#create-a-service

Comment: I already tried to use `LoadBalancer` service and it is stuck at `pending` and I don't lnow how to connect it to the cloud `LB`

Comment: Did you run minikube service yourservicename?